# Is there a way to specify an operator as an argument in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a piece of code like so:

```
var emptyKeys = (from recs in allRecords
                         where recs.Key == string.Empty
                         orderby recs.Key
                         select recs).ToList();
```

this gives me only those recs which have an empty string as key values.

To get the recs with values all that changes is the == to !=

So is it possible to put this piece of code in a method which will change the comparison from == to != based on what's required or do I repeat the query to do it like so:

```
var emptyKeys = (from recs in allRecords
                         where recs.Key != string.Empty
                         orderby recs.Key
                         select recs).ToList();
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite, but if you slightly modify your LINQ query, you can do something of the sort:

```
Func<string, string, bool> selectorFunc = (a, b) => a == b;
var emptyKeys = (from recs in allRecords
                         where selectorFunc(recs.Key, string.Empty)
                         orderby recs.Key
                         select recs).ToList();
```

That will be the equals function.

What I would do is put them in a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, bool>> selectorDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, bool>>() 
        { {"==", (a, b) => a == b}, {"!=", (a, b) => a != b} };
```

and then use it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, bool>> selectorDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, bool>>() 
        { {"==", (a, b) => a == b}, {"!=", (a, b) => a != b} };
Func<string, string, bool> selectorFunc = selectorDictionary[operator];
var emptyKeys = (from recs in allRecords
                         where selectorFunc(recs.Key, string.Empty)
                         orderby recs.Key
                         select recs).ToList();
```

This is better than the other answers as it's expandable to other operators, too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess You are looking for something like that:

```
function GetRecs(bool EmptyKey)    
{    
   var Keys = (from recs in allRecords
                         where EmptyKey == (recs.Key == string.Empty)
                         orderby recs.Key
                         select recs).ToList();
   return Keys;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `isEmpty` filter and compare it with result of `recs.Key == String.Empty`

```
bool isEmpty = true;
var keys = (from recs in allRecords
            where (recs.Key == String.Empty) == isEmpty
            orderby recs.Key
            select recs).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that should work in principle..

```
Func<bool> notEmpty = (Key) => {return !Key.IsNullOrEmpty();}
Func<bool> empty = (Key) => {return Key.IsNullOrEmpty();}

Func<bool> comparer = notEmpty

var emptyKeys = (from recs in allRecords
                         where comparer
                         orderby recs.Key
                         select recs).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `IsStringOrEmpty`?