# Why is it not possible to pass an operator as an argument?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I was trying to write a method which has a LINQ query.

So this method:

```
DoSomething(Operator operator, string name)
{
  // if operator is ==
  // use == as comparison
  // if operator is !=
  // use != as comparison

  // pseudo query
  var result = from rec in collection
               where rec.name operator name
               select rec;
 }
```

I know this can be done using delegates and Func and Action and it was explained very elegantly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022423/is-there-a-way-to-specify-an-operator-as-an-argument-in-linq).

But what I wanted to know is why a method takes only a type?
Why doesn't the CLR allow an operator to be passed as an argument to a method?
What's the idea behind the design?

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't actually use the operator you pass in anywhere.

Comment: Probably because the feature is not [worth more than 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)

Comment: I would like to ask, why would you want that feature to be implemented?

Comment: In this specific example, you shouldn't care that you are applying some kind of binary operation and should simply accept a predicate such as `Predicate<string>` or `Func<string, bool>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say quite simply because that's just not how operators are handled. Consider a class like this:

```
public class A
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

and now consider this code:

```
var a1 = new A() { Prop = 1 };
var a2 = new A() { Prop = 2 };
```

at the moment I'd need to do this:

```
if (a1.Prop == a2.Prop)
```

and that would work, but what if I could just do this:

```
if (a1 == a2)
```

and that really meant the aforementioned. That's what operators do. That's why you can't pass them as parameters. In fact, the code I just showed is more concise than what you're offering. Why not just overload the operators like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(A a1, A a2)
{
    return a1.Prop == a2.Prop;
}
```

or in your case, run the appropriate query in the overload. Simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

The CLR has nothing to do with this. Operators only exist at the language level, and boil down to static methods (possibly with some flags) when compiled to IL. Those static method use standard names like `op_Addition`, but this only to ease compatibility between languages that support operator overloading. The static method that implements `operator ==`, for example, could perfectly well be passed in as a `Func<T, T, bool>`.

As to why C# specifically does not allow an operator to be interpreted as a method group and converted to a matching delegate type, I can see a few reasons. First, this is more of a functional programming kind of thing, whereas the design of C# was to stay with familiar OOP/Java-ish kind of constructs (though they have expanded on that since then). Second, what would be the syntax? `DoSomething(==, "foo")` probably creates lots of ambiguities in the grammar, and a C++ish `DoSomething(operator==, "foo")` is starting to get really unnecessarily complex. Finally, this is probably something that wouldn't be used very much or even known to C# programmers, and remember that [all features start at -100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).