# Pass Relational Operator as an argument in Method

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, operator-keyword

I am a newbie. I would like to do something like:

```cs
private int myLoop (int start, int end, string relationalOperator)
{
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
                if ( X +relationalOperator+ Y) 
                    count++;
        }
        return count;
}
```

And then do:

```cs
myLoop(1,10,>=);
```

So I can pass a relational operator as an argument. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. See e.g. [Why is it not possible to pass an operator as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17036696)

However, you *can* pass a delegate. This would actually be more flexible, because the caller could use more complex logic than simply some comparison operator. But that's usually not going to be a problem.

In your example, it might look something like this:

```cs
private int myLoop (int start, int end, Func<int, int, bool> op)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (op(X, Y))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```cs
myLoop(1, 10, (x, y) => x >= y);
```

(I don't know what `X` and `Y` are supposed to represent in your original example, so I just left those as-is. You can use whatever `int` value you like there.)

The `Func<int, int, bool>` is a *delegate* type, which is a sort of function pointer. I.e. it can point to a function to be executed. That particular delegate type is built into .NET, and represents any method that takes two `int` parameters and returns a `bool` value. You can also declare your own custom delegate types using the `delegate` keyword. See [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

The delegate instance can be created in a variety of ways. In the example above, `(x, y) => x >= y` is a *lambda* expression. The C# compiler turns that into an *anonymous method* that in this particular example takes two parameters, evaluates the expression `x >= y` using those parameters, and returns the result. The parameter types are inferred as `int` by the compiler based on the context, in this case the method you're calling.